# How to properly create a NSTableCellView with a table that has dynamically created columns

Tags: macos, swift3, nstableview, nstablecellview

I'm trying to create a desktop application for macOS using Swift 3.

My window has two view-based tables, where one table shows a list of packets with the size of the payload. When a packet is selected, the second table shows the payload bytes. Since the payload size varies the second table has programmatically created columns; the largest packet size selected determine the maximum number of columns.

I have no problems if I use cell-based tables, but I prefer to use view-based for both tables.

The columns are created

```
for i in numCols ..< maxCols {

  let col = NSTableColumn()
  col.identifier = "Byte\(i)ColumnID"
  col.headerCell.stringValue = "[\(i)]"
  tableViewPayload.addTableColumn(col)

}
```

The problem appears in the `viewFor` delegate method, where

```
tableView.make(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
```

returns `nil`

It works if I return a `NSTextField` directly or create a `NSTableCellView` with a `NSTextField` as a subview:

```
let frameRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (tableColumn?.width)!, height: 20)      
let cell = NSTableCellView(frame: frameRect)
cell.identifier = (tableColumn?.identifier)!      

let textField = NSTextField(frame: cell.frame)
textField.stringValue = "Test"
cell.addSubview(textField)

return cell
```

This approach requires more styling of the cell and I should probably subclass `NSTableCellView`.

My question is why doesn't the `make(withIdentifier:owner:)` method work with dynamically created columns? Am I missing something when I create the columns?

Is there a way I can create a `NSTableCellView` and make use of the `textField` property?

Comment: `make(withIdentifier:owner:)` loads the cell view from a NIB. It is explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for showing that the NSTableCellView requires the NSTextField be added as a subview. Naturally an NSImageView requires the same. Now what I was trying to do works too.

Answer (score 0):

I build entire NSTableViews up programmatically. Assume you are asking about the NSTableView.makeView method. I'm using swift 4.

You know any column you create for the table gets bound to it, and vis versa?

For each column created for the table, I call

```
column.tableView = tableview
tableview.addTableColumn(column)
```